# Page ID in AdCreative Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am building some platform for advertising automatization using Facebook Marketing API. Now I am trying to execute Ad creation. One of the last steps there is setting up Ad Creative object which is responsible for Ad representation. Here is my code:

```php
public function createCreative() {
        $link_data = new LinkData();
        $link_data->setData(array(
            LinkDataFields::MESSAGE => 'try it out',
            LinkDataFields::LINK => 'http://nomer.beeline.kz/ru/Numbers?utm_source=fb&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=010681',
            LinkDataFields::CAPTION => 'My caption',
            LinkDataFields::IMAGE_HASH => 'aaf5226d9a8121e0dd30670565f00005',
        ));

        $object_story_spec = new ObjectStorySpec();
                $object_story_spec->setData(array(
                    ObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $link_data,
                    ObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => 178928252129734
        ));

        $creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_'.$this->account_id);

        $creative->setData(array(
            AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative',
            AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
        ));

        $creative->create();
```

After execution I got this error:

```
FacebookAds\Http\Exception\RequestException

Invalid parameter
```

I think it's `PAGE_ID` parameter, actually I don't know what should be there. I pasted the `ID` of my public page, where all ads actions occur. 
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`PAGE_ID` parameter is correct. Actually issue is with  `$link_data` where you are missing `CALL_TO_ACTION`

```
$link_data = new LinkData();
$link_data->setData(array(
  LinkDataFields::MESSAGE => 'try it out',
  LinkDataFields::LINK => '<URL>',
  LinkDataFields::CAPTION => 'My caption',
  LinkDataFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => array(
    'type' => CallToActionTypes::SIGN_UP,
    'value' => array(
      'link' => '<URL>',
      'link_caption' => 'Sign up!',
    ),
  ),
));

$object_story_spec = new ObjectStorySpec();
$object_story_spec->setData(array(
  ObjectStorySpecFields::PAGE_ID => <PAGE_ID>,
  ObjectStorySpecFields::LINK_DATA => $link_data,
));

$creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>');

$creative->setData(array(
  AdCreativeFields::NAME => 'Sample Creative',
  AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_STORY_SPEC => $object_story_spec,
));

$creative->create();
```

Facebook Marketing API Documentation [Ad Creative Link Data](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative-link-data/)